# How ignore Deprecated Functionality: Optional parameter $data declared before required parameter

Tags: magento2, coding-standards

As we know Magento latest version 2.4.5 version is compatible with PHP-8.x. When running setup:di: compile, it throws an exception

```
Deprecated Functionality: Optional parameter $data declared before required parameter $requiredVarible in file on line 10
```

I know its coding standing always declares required params before optional params but some of this kind of work was done many years ago, now more than 100 modules and 10,000 + methods have this mistake of optional params declared before required parameters.

Example :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $mainTable,
    $eventPrefix,
    $eventObject,
    $resourceModel,
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
    $connection = null,
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $roleFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession,
    \TM\Comet\Helper\Data $cometHelper
)
```

[image]

I have to fix it by change the position of optional params with required param
Solution :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    $mainTable,
    $eventPrefix,
    $eventObject,
    $resourceModel,
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\RoleFactory $roleFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession,
    \TM\Comet\Helper\Data $cometHelper,
    $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
    $connection = null
)
```

Can we ignore this exception? or any quick solution to fix this I have changed 100 files but need too much more work to fix this, I want if any way to bypass this standard(require param before optional param).

Your suggestions will be appreciated,Thanks in advance

Comment: Add here that file path with upload code pls.

Comment: Share the file code into question.

Comment: @RohanHapani and Dhiren, I have updated the question.